# Let $E/F$ be an algebraic field extension, then is $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)\to\mathrm{Gal}(E^{\mathrm{sep}}/F)$ an isomorphism?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be an algebraic field extension of fields in characteristic $p>0$, and let $E^{\mathrm{sep}}\subseteq E$ denote the separable closure of $F$ in $E$. Note then that we have a map $$\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)\to\operatorname{Gal}(E^{\mathrm{sep}}/F)$$ defined by taking the restriction. Now, this is clearly injective, since if $\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ restricts to $\mathrm{id}_{E^{\mathrm{sep}}}$ on ${E^{\mathrm{sep}}}$ and $\alpha\in E$, then letting $\alpha^{p^k}\in E^{\mathrm{sep}}$ gives that $\sigma(\alpha)^{p^k} = \sigma(\alpha^{p^k})=\alpha^{p^k}$ so that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$.

However, I don't necessarily see why we should be able to extend any $\sigma_0\in\operatorname{Gal}(E^{\mathrm{sep}}/F)$ to some $\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$. My main difficulty is that, for any $\alpha\in E/E^{\mathrm{sep}}$ with minimal polynomial $x^{p^k}-\alpha^{p^k}$, I don't see why we must have that $\sigma_0(\alpha^{p^k})$ is a $p^k$'th power in $E$.

The reason I think this theorem must be true is that in Serre's *Local Fields*, we prove a result about $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ by using $\operatorname{Gal}(E^{\mathrm{sep}}/F)$ in its place (though we may have used the fact that $E/F$ is normal).